# What is the realtionship between HTTP Basic Auth and .htpasswd based Authentication?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, nginx, basic-authentication

There are several approachs of the HTTP authentication: `Basic Authentication`, `Digest Access Authentication`, `NTLM HTTP Authentication` (any other ones)?

On the other side there is a `.htaccess` & `.htpasswd` based authenticazion on Apache web servers and an analog variant with the `.htpasswd` on nginx.

I want to understand: What is the `.htpasswd` based authentication on Apache and nginx actually. What is the realtionship between it and the HTTP Basic Authentication? Is it something like "implementation" of the concept? If yes, whuch other implementation are there?

The Basic HTTP Authentication uses a simle `user:password` schema.

Answer (score 3):

There are only two standard HTTP authentication methods: *Basic access authentication* (part of HTTP/1.0 spec, [RFC1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11)) and *Digest access authentication* (latest according to [RFC2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617)).

`.htpasswd` is just a common name for a file of *Apache*'s flat-file format used to store user credentials. It is managed by either `htpasswd` (basic) or `htdigest` (digest) command-line utilities. *nginx* just doesn't reinvent the wheel and uses *Apache*'s established format. For example, on Debian there's `apache2-utils` with the two aforementioned utilities (and some others), so you can install utilities separately from the server.

`.htaccess` is just Apache's ad hoc per-directory way override configuration.

Comment: The hash code/header for user:password "a:a" is `Authorization: Basic YTph`

But the code in .htpasswd is: `a:$apr1$w70ouqx8$IQ/WQfKx2Rm1/lrtK/vs4.`

So its is very different. We need to understand why?

Comment: That's done to protect passwords at rest i.e. not store them in clear text (or reversible scheme like base64 in Basic). From `man htpasswd`: *htpasswd  encrypts  passwords  using  either bcrypt, a version of MD5 modified for Apache, SHA1, or the system's crypt() routine. Files managed by htpasswd may contain a mixture  of different  encoding types of passwords* i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function#Password_hashing.